# What is the purpose of these passive high and low pass filters with this audio DAC which already has internal filtering?

Tags: filter, dac

The CS4334 is an Audio DAC. It already has internal on chip filtering and interpolation capabilities as clear from datasheet page 12 Figure 8. I assume that this means that no filter is require to remove the high frequency components that are typical of outputs on DACs. However, the recommended connection diagram on page 4 Figure 1 of the datasheet looks like this:

[image]

Questions

(1) Why are there networks of resistors and capacitors at the output?

(2) Why is load shown as resistive, should it not be inductive as speakers are represented? If a power amplifier is being used at the output that this makes sense. But then why is there in arrow pointed to right after the RL?

(3) Why is C variable? Certainly if we want to get a specific frequency response, we should have fixed values for RC in the high and low pass filters.

Comment: (2) No speakers are represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to  CS4334 datasheet, internal filter is good down to -50 -60dB only. Apparently, to meet the advertised 88/96dB noise level, a bit of extra low-pass filtering is required.

The capacitor is not "variable", it is a normal symbol for an electrolytic polarized capacitor.

The Rload, I think, is a generic test load of a headphone. This tiny detail should not be much of concern.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that besides C value of other components is fixed regardless of the load but the C depends on the load, I wonder why. I infer that your reached the conclusion by reading the datasheet fully and this conclusion is not based on explicit information from the datasheet as I have read the datashsheet myself.

Comment: I wonder why we have a low pass filter and a high pass filter. I did assume that a low pass filter would be enough to attenuate the high frequency components in the signal.

Comment: The high-pass filter is a must, to prevent possible DC from damaging headphones. It is a usual practice in audio to cut DC at frequency that matches low-frequency response of speakers or headphones. And yes, I did look into frequency response plots for their filters.

Comment: Actually, I now think that the RL represents input impedance of a power amplifier that is meant to follow. It could be 100k  or more, and the explicit formula for C is just a small over-engineering.

Comment: OK, thank you Ali. There is just 1 more question left. While they are show RL in the diagram, as far as I understand no (Audio) DAC in this world is design to drive a speaker load directly. Doing that needs a lot of power. Therefore, once the filtering is done passively as shown above, or actively using opamp based filters, as far as I understand, I must use an amplifier e.g the LM386 before the output can drive a speaker

Comment: Yes, according to the same datasheet, max load is 3 kOhms, so this device can't drive any real load, and must have an amplifier. Even for headphones, which have a typical  impedance of 32 Ohms.

Comment: Earphones have 1500Ω, IIRC. Those had been good for crystal radios.

Comment: @Janka , You must be a really seasoned engineer if you remember such things a crystal radio :-)

Comment: Nah, it was one of the experiments in my *first little radio kit*. But it was a huge disappointment as I only got one station, DLF from the 800kW transmitter 20km away. For that one, you'd only need your amalgam fillings. [^.^;]

Comment: Hmmm, what would happen if wrong value of C was used e.g if RL is not known. I would expect the inputs of any audio amplifier IC used at output of this DAC to have very high input impedance.

Comment: Nothing will happen, maybe a bit dull sound on one side, or a bit more noise on the other end. High input impedance does not matter much, the main filter is t=560*C.

Comment: This post has been most helpful. So I will clarify one more thing. It is obvious that the 3.3u Capacitor and the 10k resistor form a high pass filter. Similarly the 560ohm resistor and C form a low pass filter. But, what is the function of the 267kohm resistor that directly shunts the output to the ground? One possibility could be to convert current output to voltage. However, I am not sure if that is true in this case.

Comment: I suspect the presence of "pull-down" 267kOhm resistor is related to output transient control, where the DC decoupling cap must be discharged to eliminate "pop-up" sounds, see section 4.5 of the CS4334 datasheet. But I really have no idea...